# Lisp execution order and async call-process

Tags: emacs

I have the following code:

```
((lambda()
   (defvar buffer-name)
   (setq buffer-name "*mongo-dev*")
   (switch-to-buffer-other-window buffer-name)
   (call-process "sleep" nil buffer-name  nil "2")
  ))
```

There are 2 unexpected behaviours

1. looks the `call-process` always executed before the `switch-to-buffer-xxx`. how can I make `switch-to-buffer` executed first?
2. when executing the above code, my emacs hang for 2 seconds, is there a way for call-process to run asynchronously?

BTW, in Emacs, is there a built-in format for elisp code?

Comment: for the ones who still confused with the question 1, a workaround is to add `(redisplay t)` after the `(switch-to-buffer-other-window ...)`.  but looks @coredump provide a more general solution for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Switch to buffer

Use existing macros. For example, the following switches to a buffer (and creates it if necessary) and writes something in it. All the code inside `(with-current-buffer-window ...)` is executed in a context where the selected buffer is active and visible.

```
(with-current-buffer-window "*mongo-dev*" nil nil
  (insert "Hello"))
```

The above being a macro, it is expanded into code before being evaluated. Calling `macroexpand-all` on the code (notice the quote `'`), you can see what is the result of code transformation:

```
(macroexpand-all '(with-current-buffer-window "*mongo-dev*" nil nil
                   (insert "Hello")))

(let* ((buffer (temp-buffer-window-setup "*mongo-dev*"))
       (standard-output buffer)
       window
       value)
  (save-current-buffer
    (set-buffer buffer)
    (setq value (progn (insert "Hello")))
    (setq window (temp-buffer-window-show buffer nil)))
  (if (functionp nil)
      (funcall nil window value)
    value))
```

#### Spawning a process and using a buffer to see its output

This is is a common task, you may want to use the following instead:

```
(start-process-shell-command "my-process"
                             "*mongo-dev*"
                             "ls -la /usr/bin")
```

#### Your code

```
(defvar buffer-name)
```

`defvar` is only for global variable declarations, as toplevel statements. You rarely (never) need to put a `defvar` inside a function.

```
(setq buffer-name "*mongo-dev*")
```

What you wanted to do instead is a local binding (the "buffer-name" symbol is used as a local variable inside the body of `let`).

```
(let ((buffer-name "*mongo-dev*"))
  (switch-to-buffer-other-window buffer-name)
  (call-process "sleep" nil buffer-name  nil "2"))
```

[`call-process`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html)  is synchronous, you have other options, but this is too broad to detail here. See manual.

> BTW, in Emacs, is there a built-in format for elisp code?

Yes, [`emacs-lisp-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Executing-Lisp.html).

Comment: Thanks for your code review and suggestions,  now my problem is resolved greatly！

Comment: as for the code format,  I didn't find out the command in `emacs-lisp-mode`,  instead, I use `elisp-format.el`, the result is acceptable.